# Script is failing to acknowledge folders even though they exist

Tags: linux, perl, permissions, cgi

I have the following folders:

```
uploads
orig
temp
```

and they all exist in on the server with 777 permission:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/hghqX.png

and the script that checks the permissions is:

```
   # temp dir
   push @tests, -d $temp_dir ? 'temp dir exist: OK' : 'temp dir exist: ERROR';
   push @tests, mkdir("$temp_dir/test") ? 'temp dir mkdir: OK' : 'temp dir mkdir: ERROR';
   push @tests, rmdir("$temp_dir/test") ? 'temp dir rmdir: OK' : 'temp dir rmdir: ERROR';
   # upload dir
   push @tests, -d $upload_dir ? 'upload dir exist: OK' : 'upload dir exist: ERROR';
   push @tests, mkdir("$upload_dir/test") ? 'upload dir mkdir: OK' : 'upload dir mkdir: ERROR';
   push @tests, rmdir("$upload_dir/test") ? 'upload dir rmdir: OK' : 'upload dir rmdir: ERROR';
   # orig dir
   push @tests, -d $orig_dir ? 'orig dir exist: OK' : 'orig dir exist: ERROR';
   push @tests, mkdir("$orig_dir/test") ? 'orig dir mkdir: OK' : 'orig dir mkdir: ERROR';
   push @tests, rmdir("$orig_dir/test") ? 'orig dir rmdir: OK' : 'orig dir rmdir: ERROR';
   # htdocs dir
   push @tests, -d $img_dir ? 'img dir exist: OK' : 'img dir exist: ERROR';
   push @tests, mkdir("$img_dir/test") ? 'img dir mkdir: OK' : 'img dir mkdir: ERROR';
   push @tests, rmdir("$img_dir/test") ? 'img dir rmdir: OK' : 'img dir rmdir: ERROR';
```

and all the folder checks return an error!!!!

can anyone think what the problem is?!?!

**EXTRA INFO ABOUT VARS**

```
 temp_dir => '/var/www/cgi-bin/temp',
 upload_dir => '/var/www/cgi-bin/uploads',
 cgi_dir => '/var/www/cgi-bin',
 htdocs_dir => '/var/www/htdocs',
 htdocs_tmp_dir => '/var/www/htdocs/tmp',
```

Comment: You need to write a function. Duplication of a code is very bad.

Comment: Where are `$tmp_dir`, `$upload_dir`, `$orig_dir`, `$img_dir` initialized?  What are they set to?  What is the current directory of the process?  Are the names in the variables set to relative paths or absolute paths?  What is the base directory where the folders exist.  Where is the analogue of `$img_dir`?

Comment: I have added the vars to the question, but no all the paths are absolute!

Comment: @lollo there is a function that tests everything, and the code above is only a part of it to be honest! and this code has worked on my other servers so its extremely confusing for me, I am not sure if its the code or the apache setting!! I would appreciate any suggestion regarding configs that could cause this.

Comment: push $! on error to get the errorno

Comment: Maybe wrapping an argument will help? `-d` expects an expression as its argument, so perl may first evaluate `?:` operator, then pass the result to -d function. `push @tests, -d($temp_dir) ? 'temp dir exist: OK' : 'temp dir exist: ERROR';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your four-line repeated fragment of code:

```
# temp dir
push @tests, -d $temp_dir ? 'temp dir exist: OK' : 'temp dir exist: ERROR';
push @tests, mkdir("$temp_dir/test") ? 'temp dir mkdir: OK' : 'temp dir mkdir: ERROR';
push @tests, rmdir("$temp_dir/test") ? 'temp dir rmdir: OK' : 'temp dir rmdir: ERROR';
```

should be in a subroutine:

```
sub check_dir()
{
    my($dir) = @_;
    push @tests, (-d $dir)          ? "$dir exist: OK'      : "$dir exist: ERROR $!";
    push @tests, mkdir("$dir/test") ? "$dir/test mkdir: OK" : "$dir/test mkdir: ERROR $!";
    push @tests, rmdir("$dir/test") ? "$dir/test rmdir: OK" : "$dir/test rmdir: ERROR $!";
}

check_dir($temp_dir):
check_dir($upload_dir);
check_dir($orig_dir);
check_dir($img_dir);
```

This assumes that `@tests` is accessible to `check_dir()`, of course.  It also wraps the `-d` in parentheses, which might prevent misinterpretation of the argument.

It is interesting that you list:

```
temp_dir => '/var/www/cgi-bin/temp',
upload_dir => '/var/www/cgi-bin/uploads',
cgi_dir => '/var/www/cgi-bin',
htdocs_dir => '/var/www/htdocs',
htdocs_tmp_dir => '/var/www/htdocs/tmp',
```

which does not include `$img_dir` as listed in the original code.  This also looks like an initializer for a hash.  Let's assume the hash is `%dir_list`.  Are you sure you didn't mean to
use:

```
check_dir($dir_list{temp_dir});
```

Etcetera.  If you don't show us exactly the code you're executing, the the answers you get will be less accurate than if you show us executable code that we can test and analyze.